# How plot datetime.time in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two arrays I want to display :

```
x : [datetime.time(0, 17, 47, 782000), ...ect
y : [1712, 2002, ...ect
```

I'm trying to convert x to the format used by matplotlib but it never woks

```
x = [matplotlib.dates.date2num(i) for i in x]
```

But I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

My problem is linked with the time format :
The raw info is like this :

```
00:04:49.251
```

Then I convert it

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
```

So the type is

```
<type 'datetime.time'>
```

Comment: Seems that maplotlib wants a datetime not a time object.

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that you specify `datetime.time` objects which only have the information on the time of day. As `Emanuele Paolini` points out in their comment, `matplotlib` expects to have `datetime.datetime` objects which carry the date in addition to the time.

You may carry out the conversion:

```
import datetime

my_day = datetime.date(2014, 7, 15)
x_dt = [ datetime.datetime.combine(my_day, t) for t in x ]
```

Now you may use `x_dt` with the `plot` function.

The downside of this approach is that you may get the date somewhere on your plot, but that can be tackled by changing the label settings.

Comment: I think matplotlib should introduce the ability to plot by datetime.time or other "clock-time" datatypes like it does for datetime. Some data are just in that format, and right now you need to turn it into a datetime object (add a random and useless date component that may have no meaning in your usecase) and then extract it out with label formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the time module where as it expects a datetime object.

for the error you can use something like this, ( I am 99% sure this should solve the error)

```
from datetime import datetime

dates.append(datetime.strptime(row[5], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"))
```